# Rails 5: Two search form_tags on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to implement a two `search form_tag` on a the same page, each search form is placed inside `dynamic bootstrap tabs`. The first one which is working is basic a search form with one field. The second one which is not working has two fields, one is the same search method as the first and the other I'm trying to get the address from the `other_location` field and via `params[:other_location]`. 
With the current setup the `other_location` field form the second form does not appear!

Both of the forms are inside partials and I am rendering them inside two `dynamic bootstrap tabs` like this:

```
<%= render 'pages/search' %>
<%= render 'pages/search_other' %>


<%= form_tag search_items_path, :method => "get" do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], autofocus: true,
                   class: "search-query search_size",
                   placeholder: "Enter product to search" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, :style => "display: none;" %>
<%end%>


<%= form_for :search_other_path, :method => "get" do |form| %>
<%= form.text_field :search, autofocus: true,
                   class: "search-query search_size",
                   placeholder: "Enter keyword to search" %>

  <% form.fields_for :other_location_path, :method => "get" do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :other_location, class: "search-query search_size",
                     placeholder: "Enter address to search" %>

<%= form.submit "Search", name: nil, :style => "display: none;" %>
<%end%>
<%end%>
```

model

```
def self.search(search)
  return where("0=1") if search !~ /\w{4}/
  where("lower(title) LIKE lower(:term)", term: "%#{search}%")
end
```

routes.rb

```
get 'search' => 'pages#search', as: 'search_posts'
get 'search' => 'pages#search_other', as: 'search_other'
get 'search' => 'pages#other_location', as: 'other_location'
```

controller:

```
def search_other
  if params[:search]
    @posts = Post.near(other_location,10).search(params[:search]).page(params[:page])
  else
    @posts = []
  end
end

def other_location
  other_location = params[:other_location]
  if params[:other_location]
  Geocoder.search(params[:other_location])
  end
end


def search
  if params[:search]
    @posts = Post.near(action,10).search(params[:search]).page(params[:page])
  else
    @posts = []
  end
end
```

Comment: Add some console logs. Since you're using 'dynamic bootstrap tabs' , it might a JS problem. So any errors in the browser console, add them as well.

Comment: @Vlad the weird thing is that I'm getting no errors.. it seems like the `search fom_tag`  is not loading after I press enter. Not sure whats wrong!

Comment: If you are using turbolinks then second form object reference lost so for debugging please remove the turbolinks and check.

Comment: thanks for the reply @vivek singh, nope I'm not using `turbolinks`

Comment: Even if I use the same exact search `form_tag` on the same page and without the `bootstrap tabs`, the one `search_form_tag` doesn't work! Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: First thing I'd try is to write the 2 forms outside of any JS action, let them render Rails way, statically on a page, and see if that works. If they do work, then most than likely there's some JS issue.

Comment: I tried that too @Vlad... I'm just rendering the two form_tags on the same page without any bootstrap tabs, js or even styling div's. And even tried by duplicating and using the same exact form_tags, but nothing, it dosen't work! Not sure why though!

Comment: Why do you have params in your views ? Usually the params is a way to retrieve the fields once in the controller. This may be the reason.

Comment: I'm using the `params` for that exact reason! It's a search form_tag and this one of the controller methods: `def search
    if params[:search]
      @items = Item.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @items = []
    end end`

Answer (score 1):

On your route file:

```
get 'search/other' => 'pages#search_other', as: 'search_other'
get 'search' => 'pages#search_other', as: 'search_other_items'
```

both GET requests are going to your pages_controller.rb #`search_other` method. So even if you have the two `form_tag`s sending the data to different paths (`search_other_path`, and `search_other_items_path`) it would be going to the same controler method - which is redundant.

On your actual HTML you have two form tags:

```
<%= form_tag search_items_path, :method => "get" do %>
```

and

```
<%= form_tag search_other_items_path, :method => "get" do %>
```

You have not mentioned `search_items_path` in your routes, so I have no idea where that's pointing to. Likely its a proper controller that works since you mentioned the first form was the only one working.

Now, your mentioned controller only has a `search` method. So to start you are looking at the wrong controller. You should be looking at the controller methods being referenced by the form's action.

In this case, the second form is sending it's request to `search_other_items_path` which according to your routes, its pointing to `pages_controller.rb` -> `#search_other` method.

You should edit your question to include code that is actually relevant. Maybe then I can actually help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help @mhz... yeah I noticed that, I forgot to change the routes and a few other variables and model names. But that didn't help, it's still not working. I updated the question with ALL the proper info. Take a look and let me know what u think! Thanks!

Comment: Your second form now has a nested form. Can you paste your App's debug logs when you submit the form?

Comment: I also don't understand what `search_posts_path` is being used for. Doesn't look like its being referenced in any of your forms...

Comment: Basically this is what I'm after and I don't know how to implement it... How can I add a `text_field` inside the first form that will send the values to the `other_location` action inside the controller??? One form with one submit button. That is what I'm really after!

Comment: @Theopap I'm just going to leave this here for reference - please take a read, maybe it will help clarify some things for you: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html
And huh - I think the question now has completely diverted from your original question :)